# Does calling StyleSheet.create multiple times effect performance?

Tags: css, react-native

Generally, you declare `StyleSheet.create` outside of `Component`.
However, I've added `StyleSheet.create` inside `render()` to take advantage of the `redux state` on some pages.

Every time you reRender you will call `StyleSheet.create` Is this a problem?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Button } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import TestView from './TestView';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text:{
    fontSize:14,
  }
})

const useStateStyles = fontSize => StyleSheet.create({
   text:{
    fontSize:fontSize,
  }
})

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    fontSize:14,
  }

  render() {
    const { fontSize } = this.state;
    this.styles = useStateStyles(fontSize);
    return (
    <View style={{flex:1,marginTop:20}}>
    <Button 
    title="+"
    onPress={()=>{this.setState({
      fontSize:fontSize+2
    })}}
    />
    <Button 
    title="-"
    onPress={()=>{this.setState({
      fontSize:fontSize-2
    })}}
    />
     <Text style={styles.text}>{fontSize}</Text>
     <Text style={this.styles.text}>{fontSize}</Text>
     </View>
    );
  }
}
```

If `StyleSheet.create` is external and fixed, it can't be changed when the `State` changes.
So call `useStateStyles` in `render`.

https://snack.expo.io/SJOMaiwXH

Comment: Is there a reason to call StyleSheet.create multiple times?

Comment: @hongdevelop 
Added information to the post.